# Calling 'git reset --hard' from .bat results in "Cannot do hard reset with paths" error

Tags: git, batch-file, cmd

In my batch script I'm trying to clone and reset a repository using a tag:

```
git reset --hard <tagname here>
```

This returns the error "**fatal: Cannot do hard reset with paths.**"

Meanwhile, I can go into the same directory in cmd and copy in the same command and it works just fine.

It seems like with the batch file, it's interpreting the tag name argument as the name of a directory i.e. a path

I have tried using "" but this hasn't changed anything

Comment: Can you reproduce this with an empty repro, and a batch file that you could post here?

Answer (score 0):

It should work, the syntax is OK.

If its still doesn't work try this alternate way:

```
git checkout tag_name
```

It will get you in a [***`Detached HEAD`***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-back-to-a-previous-location/34519716#34519716) mode

Answer (score 0):

My mistake:

I had a tab at the end of the line followed by a comment, so it was interpreting the tab as part of a the argument. Whoops!